# My Javascript working locally but dont work on server. Why?

Tags: javascript, charts, server, localserver

I have a question to You. 
On my local server my circle charts in JS working normally but when i want to see them through www protocol i don't see them :/. I copied my files many times to server - I don't see charts.
Here is code:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/jquery.circliful.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.e-plus.com.pl/mateusz/THEMEFOREST/js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to do this with my domain adress but result is the same... Webbrowser don't see my charts :(

Comment: did you check for errors and path problems in your browser dev tools console and network tabs?

Comment: Whats your folder structure from root / project root locally as well as on the server?

Comment: Look at the paths in your `<script` tags.     Is the jQuery javascript file in a directory below the HTML page, called `js` ?    Or is it in a directory off root called `js`?   If so:

`src="/js/..."` is what you want to do.

Comment: Path at my local:
C:/xampp/htdocs/THEMEFOREST/Theme_1/js
Path on server:
www.e-plus.com.pl/mateusz(this is my website directory)/js
I tried to do src="/js/..." but then even on my local server charts are missing :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you use any

`<base href="http://...">`?

Try using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="./css/jquery.circliful.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.e-plus.com.pl/mateusz/THEMEFOREST/js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
```